# Building LibreSSL for use in a C++ project

Tags: c++, macos, clang, libressl

I am trying to write a C++ project using libressl. I have built the package and followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/libressl-portable/portable) however I have been unable to locate the header files (or any files from the make install actually) for the project.

I am fairly new to C++ development and I am not a professional programmer so there is a good chance I am doing this completely wrong. Is it even possible to use LibreSSL as a C++ library and if so what steps would I need to take to do so?

Comment: Looks like you can use CMake to generate project files or a Makefile for whatever compiler you are using. [https://cmake.org/](https://cmake.org/)

Comment: ***Is it even possible to use LibreSSL as a C++ library*** The documentation for the project [https://github.com/libressl-portable/portable#readme](https://github.com/libressl-portable/portable#readme) confirms that it works for c++ on a variety of compilers and operating systems. I have not used it myself.

Comment: With that said the Visual Studio part is a bit outdated. The current Visual Studio Community version is 2022 not 2013 but the instructions should be similar with the version difference in selecting the correct CMake generator.

Comment: For help with whatever compiler you are using on whatever OS you will have to show specific information on the steps you have taken and show any problems you have. Please try to keep text as text and not a picture of text. It is a requirement of the site to post code and errors as text.

Comment: I am using Clang on MacOS however I don't actually know what to type to even try and include these libraries when compiling. I know how to normally add .h and .cpp files however this is the first time I have tried to use a library like this one.

Comment: Probably the commands following ***If you wish to use the CMake build system, use these commands:*** Make sure you install cmake on your OS first.

Comment: ***however this is the first time I have tried to use a library like this one*** I would say good percentage of c++ libraries on github are very similar to this. You build the library from source code using your compiler. Many use CMake to help generate the proper Makefile / project file for many different compilers